# Why does query return only ID and queried params?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a database of Cards, out of which issues are divided by their `states`.

A Card has only state.

A state can be `open` or `closed`.

All of the Cards have an associated key value called boardID. Each card can have only boardID. Multiple cards can belong to one boardID.

I am trying to query the database where the state is `closed` and the `boardID` is any(one) given value. The query only yields in returning the ID of the card and the boardID but i need all the other details of the card?!

A card has many details
- cardName
- date
- description

I tried to fetch the details of the cards by nesting a for loop and finding the cards by ID and adding the results to an array.

This works, but the problem is that the process is asynchronous, and I have a `res.send()` value which fires before the data is pushed to the array.

Basic query which should fetch card details

```
let closed_cards = []
Card.find({ state: "closed" }, { boardID: b }, function (err, data) { res.send(data)
});
```

Query which fetches cards based on the id.

```
let closed_cards = []
Card.find({ state: "closed" }, { boardID: b }, function (err, data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      Card.findById(data[i]._id, function (err, e) {
        closed_cards.push(e)
      })
    }

    if (closed_cards != []) {
      res.send(closed_cards)
    }
  })
```

In the second case, because of the asynchronous behavior the res.send() sends an empty array.

Ideally, `Card.find` should have done the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) here, `Card.find({ state: "closed" }, { boardID: b }` will return all card with state closed and select `boardID` field from them because second parameter `{ boardID: b }` is projection. The correct query should be `Card.find({ state: "closed", boardID: b }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Card.find({ $and: [{"state": "closed"}}, { "boardID": b }]})
```

I usually use `$` and I open an `array` for what I need, especially useful if I search several states